# How to deal with late answers for no longer supported releases in the review queue?

Tags: support, close-reasons

Example: [Very late answer to a question regarding 18.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130767/how-do-you-autologin-in-lubuntu-18-10/1202954#1202954)

Yes, it isn't really an answer, but I wished to know, how it is generally regulated? Whatever the quality of the answer is.

Comment: I would do nothing, the question was on topic when it was asked and there is no time limit for answering questions. What makes you think this is something that needs regulating? I can't really see how it is a problem.

Comment: Nothing. Late answers also lead to a badge so ... nothing IF the answer is a good answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do nothing.  As long as it seems like a suitable answer we leave it alone.

This said, if the post is spammy, not related, or similar then we address it.  Otherwise, we leave the questions be - no need to touch something that's not really 'broken'.

Comment: Do nothing? What if it needs editing, voting on or comments to suggest improvements? :P I would say *just treat it like any other answer*